# Creating launcher animations in android

Tags: java, android, animation, button, android-animation

I am thinking about making a launcher for android, i dont know if i'll market it. But i'm thinking like my phone is in landscape mode, and i see 4 rows of buttons, and 4 buttons on each row. Kind of like a grid with buttons. And then, once i click a button, i want the buttons splitted in the middle and moved from each other, with an animation. And then a second screen comes in from the back. How can i do this? I thought of creating two layouts holding 4 buttons each, and once i click one, it should move the layouts from each other and the second blank screen would kind of fly in from the back, like if it was behind the buttons. How can i create these animations? Please help me and thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a middle row with width initially as 0dp, and then when opening an Activity you could animate its width, and for the second screen you can use a simple zoomIn animation with overridePendingTransition() after startActivity()

Comment: smart, i'll give it a try and get back to you

Comment: I understand what you mean, but i dont know how to do this? Could you provide an example